# Is it possible to display a text file in two or more columns without changing the text file itself?

Tags: column, follow-mode

Is it possible to display a text file in two or more columns without changing the text file itself?

I sometimes deal with a text file that contains a long list each of whose items are short. By default, if I had a list like below:

```
* a
* b
* c
* d
```

and if I have vertically extremely limited space on the screen, it'll be displayed like this:

```
* a
* b
```

I'd like to make it displayed like this:

```
window1 window2 
* a     * c
* b     * d
```

And if I inserted a new org heading at the end of my list, it should be like this:

```
window1 window2
* b     * d
* c     * _
```

(_ is the point)

And the whole text file should be like this:

```
* a
* b
* c
* d
*
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want `follow-mode`. It comes with emacs.
First, show the same buffer in two side by side windows (Ctl-x 3).
Then turn on follow-mode. Page up and down, and watch the magic.

Comment: Thanks, Jon, it works! I didn't expect it was that simple!